# How can I view Jira in a different interface

Tags: jira

This might be a very stupid question but I have been struggling with it for a bit. Im looking for this interface:

[image]

However, I only get this one.

[image]

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean the white or black theme?

Answer (score 0):

Atlassian have disabled the old view for everyone. It's a mandatory switch to the new "view". We can only change the "Theme", which can be done from the top right corner.
[image: Change theme in Jira]

Answer (score 0):

[Settings menu of Jira](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeFoM.png)

If you go on the top right corner on the "settings" (gear-symbol). You will find this settings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).